# Even with pygame initialized "video system not initialized" gets thrown

Tags: python, pygame

The following bit of code throws an error:

```
while True:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if (event.type == ENDSONG):
            queue_song()
```

This it what it reads:

```
  File "pygametest.py", line 22, in <module>
  event = pygame.event.wait()
  pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Most of the digging I've done says that the error stems from pygame.init() not being run, but that's what starts my code.

Am I missing something else?

Edit: Added Code.

```
import pygame
import time

def queue_song():
        print "Queueing New Song"

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
#rest of code
```

Comment: show the bit where you call `pygame.init()` it most likely isn't getting called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you initialize Pygame, you need to call to `display.set_mode` to avoid this error:

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# rest of the code
```

This happens because the event queue needs the video mode to be set to work properly. From the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> The input queue is heavily dependent on the pygame display module. If the display has not been initialized and a video mode not set, the event queue will not really work.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I'm only using the sound playing/streaming part of pygame, but I need to be able to catch the end.  Is there any other way to catch the event that gets thrown when you use set_endevent()?  Or is it the nature of the beast that I need to use pygame.event.wait()?

Comment: @ballofpopculture Instead of `while True:`, you can use the [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) function for the condition of the loop. Thus, you don't need any event to know when the music has finished.

Comment: The one problem with this is that get_busy() only returns false when no music is playing.  It returns true even if the currently playing song becomes the queue song.  There are ways around this, but queueing a song to play after the current song is part of the plan, though there are ways around this that don't use the endevent() or get_busy()